# How unescape strings in json with ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, json

Here is json string:

```
 {
    "app":"${host}\":\"${post}"
 }
```

How unwrap strings? E.g. how to produce this:

```
{
    app:${host}":"${post}
}
```

Leading and trailing double quotes are deleted, escaped double quotes become unescaped.

How to do this with ruby?

**Also**

In java I can use appache commons [StringEscapeUtil.unescapeJson](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJson(java.lang.String)) Is there analog in ruby?

**Important**

1. yep, the result will not be valid json file. This is expected.
2. I can use something like `string.replace("\"", "")` and `string.replace("\\\"", "")` but it would be nice to use some out-of-the-box function (if it is).

Comment: In source code - yes, `\"` means `"`. But when I save json content to file - no, `\"` in file is not the same as `"`

Comment: There's no such functionality in ruby. According to json specification keys should be quoted, but still you can get the necesessary result by using regular exprerssions

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'json'

str =<<'END_OF_STRING'
{
    "app":"${host}\":\"${post}"
}
END_OF_STRING

puts str
puts str.gsub(/[\\]" | ["]/x, '\"' => '"', '"' => '')

--output:--
{
    "app":"${host}\":\"${post}"
}
{
    app:${host}":"${post}
}
```